# Sum of uniformly convergent sequences converges to sum of limit functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, uniform-convergence

> Prove that if $\{f_k\}$ converges uniformly to $f$ and $\{g_k\}$ converges uniformly to $g$, then $\{f_k + g_k\}$ converges uniformly to $f+g$.

I came up with this proof and I was wondering if it is OK.

First of all, this is my definition of uniform convergence:

> $f_n:T \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ converges uniformly to $f:T \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ if for each $\epsilon>0$
>    there exists $n(\epsilon)$ such that if $n \ge n(\epsilon)$ then $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ for any $x\in T$.

We want to prove that $\{f_k+g_k\} \rightarrow f+g$ uniformly, so given $\epsilon>0$ we have to prove that $\exists n(\epsilon): \forall n\geq n(\epsilon), \ \ |(f_n(x) + g_n(x)) - (f(x)+g(x))|<\epsilon.$

Let $\epsilon>0.$ We know that $\{f_k\} \rightarrow f$ uniformly and $\{g_k\} \rightarrow g$ uniformly, so:

1. $\exists n(\epsilon): \forall n\geq n(\epsilon), \ \ |f_n(x) - f(x)|
   < {\epsilon \over 2}.$
2. $\exists m(\epsilon): \forall m\geq m(\epsilon), \ \ |g_m(x) - g(x)|
   <{\epsilon \over 2}.$

Let' s consider $t_0=max\{n, m \}$. If $t\geq t_0$, then  $|(f_t(x) + g_t(x)) - (f(x)+g(x))|$ = $|(f_t(x) - f(x)) + (g_t(x)-g(x))| \leq |f_t(x) - f(x)| + |g_t(x)-g(x)| < {\epsilon \over 2}+{\epsilon \over 2}=\epsilon.$

Comment: That looks fine.

Comment: How would this look for an arbitrary metric?

Answer (score 2):

Let  $I $ be an intervall, $$F_n =\sup_I |f_n-f|$$
and
$$G_n=\sup_I  |g_n-g|.$$

then  $\forall x\in I,$

$$|(f_n+g_n) (x)-(f+g)(x)|\le $$
$$|(f_n-f)(x)|+|(g_n-g)(x)|\le$$
$$ F_n+G_n $$

and

$$ H_n=\sup_I |(f_n+g_n)-(f+g)|\le$$
$$ F_n+G_n $$

but
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty} F_n=\lim_{n\to+\infty} G_n=0$$
$$ \implies \lim_{n\to+\infty}H_n=0$$
by squeezing.

$\implies  \; (f_n+g_n) $ converges uniformly to $f+g $ at $I $.